# Partitioning php classes

Tags: php

Is there a way in PHP to split up functions in several files?

Because I have a huge class which I cannot split up for backwards compatibility reasons.

But I would like to do something like with C++ where you declare a class in one file and the function bodies in an other file.

Comment: Consider using inheritance and compositions.

Comment: At some point in time someone once said to me that if your class is considered "huge" you have probably done something wrong. The longer I do this for a living, the more I tend to agree.

Answer (score 4):

> **Warning**
>   You can NOT break up a class definition into multiple files. You also can NOT break a class definition into multiple PHP blocks, unless the break is within a method declaration.

Taken verbatim from the [php manual](http://www.php.net//manual/en/keyword.class.php).